# Why is this if statement being triggered when the list does not contain the conditions the if statement specifies?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

Why is the first if statement being triggered and not the elif statement after it?

```
player_moves = [1, 3, 4]
computer_moves = [5, 2]
if 4 and 5 in computer_moves and 6 not in player_moves:
    computer_moves.append(6)
    print("Computer chooses " + str(computer_moves[-1]))
elif 2 and 5 in computer_moves and 8 not in player_moves:
    computer_moves.append(8)
    print("Computer chooses " + str(computer_moves[-1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

`if 4 and 5 in computer_moves and 6 not in player_moves:` is same as

`if 4 and (5 in computer_moves) and (6 not in player_moves):`,

change to

`if 4 in computer_moves and 5 in computer_moves and 6 not in player_moves:`

so

`True and True and True`

Same problem in the `elif`.

`elif 2 and 5 in computer_moves and 8 not in player_moves:` same as

`elif 2 and (5 in computer_moves) and (8 not in player_moves):`

Comment: If there's a lot of numbers to check for being in the list, or a different number each time, you can also use set subset operator: `{4, 5} <= {3, 4, 5, 6}` etc